# Extracting road surface type from OSM files

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm trying to export all the road surface information (all countries) from OSM and create a layer on top of Mapbox. Is there a tool to download only the necessary information that I need? I could not find a good tutorial on this to start with.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Your question is very broad: 1. Which roads are you interested in? 2. Are you aware that the data most likely will only be partly available and/or be inconsistent? 3. Have you had a look at [overpass-turbo.eu](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) or [geofabrik.de](https://www.geofabrik.de/en/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I know it would not be consistent. I tried overpass-turbo but it only downloads a limited area not for a whole country or planet for example.

Comment: Overpass API is the wrong tool for downloading large data across the whole world. Better download a planet file and extract the information you are looking for, for example with osmium-tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though this [blog](https://www.cursosgis.com/qgis-y-python-para-analizar-datos-de-openstreetmap/) is in Spanish, it will let you know about OSM data and how to make a request from Python. You'll find the code there too.

```py
import requests
import json
overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
overpass_query = """
[out:json];
area["name"="Málaga"][admin_level=8];
(node["amenity"="restaurant"](area);
 node["amenity"="bar"](area);
 node["amenity"="cafe"](area);
);
out center;
"""
response = requests.get(overpass_url, params={'data': overpass_query})
data = response.json()
```

Another thing you can do is go to [OSM repositories](https://www.geofabrik.de/data/download.html) like Geofabrik and download manually the data that fits your needs.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please keep in mind, that links may change. Therefore, please extract the essential content and include it in your answer, while you keep the link as reference. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Erik for noting that. I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

As demonstrated by @ArturoMendes , Using Overpass API it is possible to do queries in a nice way , there is much information on the OSM Wiki, [OSM Wiki Link](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). On the OSM Wiki there is a list of public global Overpass API providers you can query against.

This list is reproduced below and is not complete

```
https://lz4.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter
https://z.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter
http://overpass.openstreetmap.fr/api/interpreter
https://overpass.kumi.systems/api/interpreter
https://overpass.nchc.org.tw
```

### Overpass-Turbo

Personally, for simple extractions, I use a graphical web application called [overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) ( [Github link](https://github.com/tyrasd/overpass-turbo) , [OSM Wiki Link](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo) )

This can be self hosted from the source provided on the Github repository or you may use the public service URL above.

Using the following query  the following is displayed (The variable '{{bbox}}' is specific to the web application and you will need to adjust for your use)

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “road”
  way["highway"="primary"]["surface"="asphalt"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Converted into XML this is

```
<osm-script output="json" output-config="" timeout="25">
  <union into="_">
    <query into="_" type="way">
      <has-kv k="highway" modv="" v="primary"/>
      <has-kv k="surface" modv="" v="asphalt"/>
      <bbox-query s="36.533364047181" w="-4.6685028076172" n="36.886211278422" e="-4.0903472900391"/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <print e="" from="_" geometry="skeleton" ids="yes" limit="" mode="body" n="" order="id" s="" w=""/>
  <recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
  <print e="" from="_" geometry="skeleton" ids="yes" limit="" mode="skeleton" n="" order="quadtile" s="" w=""/>
</osm-script>
```

[image]

### Data Extraction

Data can be extracted from the application and saved in a variety of formats

For simple display, KML and GPX, or you may save the query for use in a python application or script

[image]